# ¿Como puedo manterner con un estilo diferente un boton de los enlaces del menu de navegación?

Tags: css, web, diseño

sucede lo siguiente estoy desarrollando una página web pero, he visto y me gustaría que cuando yo le de click en un botón del menú de navegación y pase a esa página, se tener un estilo diferente en el botón del menú de navegación que me dice donde estoy. En pocas palabras quisiera decirle al usuario a través de css y los botones de navegación en que página se encuentra.

Comment: Comparte un fragmento del código involucrado (Menú, CSS, etc.)

Comment: Mira la respuesta que te dejaron abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas se realiza con la seudoclase `:active` en css, te permite definir el estilo de un enlace seleccionado, mientras está siendo seleccionado.

```
a:active { color: #ff00ff; text-decoration: none}
```

Comment: no como tal! porque ese es mientras digamos que pincho el enlace, pero creo que hay un atributo en css que es "seleted" que hace que se mantenga seleccionado un enlace sin importar si se pincho o no, es para ayudar al usuario a saber en que parte de la página esta